# Adding extra rows to the result SUMs of MariaDB/MySQL select query with SUM, WHERE group IN ("a","b") and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the DB with

| id | block | group | stat_a | stat_b | stat_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 2 | 1 | b | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 3 | 5 | a | 51 | 52 | 53 |
| 4 | 6 | b | 61 | 62 | 63 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 54 | 8 | a | 81 | 82 | 83 |

- any next row is higher number of block or the same number but different group

I want to select SUMs from stats grouped by blocks

```
SELECT block, SUM(stat_a), SUM(stat_b), SUM(stat_c)
FROM table
WHERE group IN (a, b)
GROUP BY block
```

BUT with additional conditions:

- any group which a record for block 1 and the next record is for block 5, I need to add extra results for SUM to groped groups by block as for blocks 2,3,4 with repeated results for stats_a aka extra rows:

`id, 2, "a", 11, 0, 0`

`id, 3, "a", 11, 0, 0`

`id, 4, "a", 11, 0, 0`

if only the stat_a is greater than 0 (this "if" is just for speed optimizations)

- And for all groups ("a", "b") to specify the end block as "42" and when the last record is for block 8 or 6 again to add extra rows for sums aka:

  `id, 9, "a", 81, 0, 0`

  `...........`

  `id, 42, "a", 81, 0, 0`

  `id, 7, "b", 61, 0, 0`

  `...........`

  `id, 42, "b", 61, 0, 0`

id in extra added rows is not important

if only the stat_a from last record is greater than 0 (this "if" is just for speed optimizations)

I tried

```
SELECT block, SUM(stat_a), SUM(stat_b), SUM(stat_c)
FROM table WHERE
group IN (a, b)
GROUP BY block
```

and works, but how to add additional conditions.

I have the code which works in python logic but is slow because I try to iterate any group in range of many blocks.
In one case with 65 billion calculations, the time is 4 hours and the problem is not the calculations but the many millions of iterations for any group(100k) and for range of blocks (300k-400k)

I use MariaDB 10.5

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the MariaDB / MySQL version you use.  10.2+ / 8.0 + have (Window Functions like LAG()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lag/),

Comment: The DB is MariaDB 10.5

Comment: what do you mean by "next" record?  With what sort order?

Comment: They are stored by id and blocks. Let's assume(and the real case is) the order is by block ascending.  And we have a case (id 54, group a, block 3, stats...) and for the same group a the next record ordered by blocks is (id 64, group a, block 4(or 10), stats...) added in the QUESTION